# Cocos2dx restart scene crashing CCTextureCache

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

In Cocos2dx on iOS I'm having trouble restarting the same scene.
I'm looking to restart the same scene whenever the player dies. There are a lot of things happening on at start up so if possible I'd rather not try and manually reset all the game variables, clear cache ect.

In the part that the player dies I do the following

```
cocos2d::CCScene *pScene = GameScene::scene();
cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(pScene);
```

But this leads to the following crash:

```
CCTextureCache::CCTextureCache()
{
    CCAssert(g_sharedTextureCache == NULL, "Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
    m_pTextures = new CCDictionary();
}
```

Gamescene is inherits from CCLayer and its constructor looks like this.

```
CCScene* GameScene::scene()
{
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();
    GameScene *layer = GameScene::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);     
    return scene;
}
```

The app crashes on this line GameScene *layer = GameScene::create(); but I can't really follow it any further. Am I doing anything wrong in the replacing of the scene?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Looks fine, question is: do you do anything else besides that? A common problem is to be overly eager to clean up after cocos2d - it's usually just unnecessary, sometimes counterproductive (like purging all cached data every time a scene change occurs) and in rare cases may crash (trying to dealloc director and things like that). The call stack for the crash would help.

Answer (score 0):

Although you should implement proper checks in the scene() static function but I think that may not be causing the problem.
If you can give all the code for this GameLayer class I might be able to point out your mistake because I have done what you are trying to do.

You are probably trying to do something illegal with the texture cache in your init function, that is my guess. But do post your code !